# Update Account.Name field when FirstName or LastName will be changed or new Account Created

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, process-builder

I want to update Account.Name with ( FirstName__C + LastName__C) whenever FirstName__C or LastName__C is changed or new account is created.

Workflow/process builder/trigger will not work as it will work when event is raised and Account.Name is mandatory field. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As `Name` is required so whenever a record is created you need to fill some text in it.

Now you have few options here:

1. Use URL hack to prepopulate name with some `Test text` but you need to make sure to use proper parameter in Lightning experience/Salesforce1.
2. You can replace the New page with custom VF page and from there hide the Name field and then in controller populate the Name field.

Comment: Thanks Tushar but User don't want to enter any value in Name field. They only want to put value in custom field. We can create new VF page but we have 10 record type so we have to create different VF pages for each record types.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni Either you need to create 1 pages or you can use [DescribeLayoutResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describelayout_describelayoutresult.htm) to create UI dynamically.